# How can I render a component multiple times in a page with different timing for each one in react.js

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, react-hooks, render

I have an array of objects `

```
const play = data.plays;
```

```
// [{time: "30", host: "John", booths: ["1","2","3"]},
    {time: "60", host: "Maria", booths: ["4","5","6"]},
    .
    .
    .]
```

` which I gather from a database where the user inserts. When I start the app I see a bunch of warnings and errors like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

but when I change the value of the array on `useEffect` function, I see my page except that it only renders the last object.

I try also to `useState` for the *time,host,box* but I didn't have the desired result.

`

```
function Booth(boxId, label) {

let time, host, box, allPlay

    const play = data.plays;
        console.log(play)
    
    if (play == null) {
        time = 0
        host = ''
        box = []
    }  
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        allPlay = play.map((play) => {
            time = play.time
            host = play.host
            box = play.booths
            
            console.log(time,host,box)          
    
        let timer = parseInt(time)        
       
       const currentRender = setInterval (() => {
    
                for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
                    for (let k = 0; k < name.length; k++) {
                    
                        if (box[i] === name[k].value) {
    
                            const activeBox = document.getElementById(`${box[i]}`)
                                document.getElementById(`time`+`${box[i]}`).innerText = `Time : ` + `${timer}`
                                document.getElementById(`host`+`${box[i]}`).innerText = `Host : ` + `${host}`
                        
                            if (timer > 15) {
                                activeBox.classList.add("red")
                            } else if (timer > 5){
                                activeBox.classList.add("yellow")
                            } else if (timer > 0){
                                activeBox.classList.add("green")
                            } else if (timer === 0){
                                host = ''
                                time = 0
                                activeBox.className = "white"
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
    
            if (timer > 0) {
                timer--;
            }
            
       }, 1000);   
       return () => clearInterval(currentRender);   
       
    })
        
    },[allPlay])   // react-hooks/exhaustive-deps     
                // but if i change the value of the array, it will re-render the component
    
    return (
        <div className={`box col-1`}>
            <h4>{label}</h4>
            <p className="white" id={`time`+`${boxId}`}>Time:</p>
            <p className="white" id={`host`+`${boxId}`}>Host:</p>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Booth;
```

```
\`
I have a few of these components in the page and i want to change their state by user input and of course by the time.
```

Comment: What is the value of name? Do you also want to rerender when it changes?

Comment: No. name is another array constant. the names of the boxes. One object {time,host,booths} is one play. I want to make multiple plays to render at the same time.